# Prestashop 1.6.1.6 Invalid Short Description Product using javascript

Tags: javascript, prestashop-1.6

I have a clean Prestashop 1.6.1.6 installation. I have included Javascript in a Short Description Product.

When I save my product Prestashop show me an error:

> Invalid short Description

There is no error when I only save text in my product description.

Prestashop Preferences:

- HTML Purifier=No
- Iframes HTML=YES
- Short Description long=0

How can I add javascript in short description like old Prestashop versions?

[Product error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOd4W.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `Product.php` classe's definition:

```php
'description' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'),
'description_short' => array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'),
```

You see that it uses `isCleanHtml` validator.

Here is the `isCleanHtml` validator:

```php
/**
 * Check for HTML field validity (no XSS please !)
 *
 * @param string $html HTML field to validate
 * @return bool Validity is ok or not
 */
public static function isCleanHtml($html, $allow_iframe = false)
{
    $events = 'onmousedown|onmousemove|onmmouseup|onmouseover|onmouseout|onload|onunload|onfocus|onblur|onchange';
    $events .= '|onsubmit|ondblclick|onclick|onkeydown|onkeyup|onkeypress|onmouseenter|onmouseleave|onerror|onselect|onreset|onabort|ondragdrop|onresize|onactivate|onafterprint|onmoveend';
    $events .= '|onafterupdate|onbeforeactivate|onbeforecopy|onbeforecut|onbeforedeactivate|onbeforeeditfocus|onbeforepaste|onbeforeprint|onbeforeunload|onbeforeupdate|onmove';
    $events .= '|onbounce|oncellchange|oncontextmenu|oncontrolselect|oncopy|oncut|ondataavailable|ondatasetchanged|ondatasetcomplete|ondeactivate|ondrag|ondragend|ondragenter|onmousewheel';
    $events .= '|ondragleave|ondragover|ondragstart|ondrop|onerrorupdate|onfilterchange|onfinish|onfocusin|onfocusout|onhashchange|onhelp|oninput|onlosecapture|onmessage|onmouseup|onmovestart';
    $events .= '|onoffline|ononline|onpaste|onpropertychange|onreadystatechange|onresizeend|onresizestart|onrowenter|onrowexit|onrowsdelete|onrowsinserted|onscroll|onsearch|onselectionchange';
    $events .= '|onselectstart|onstart|onstop';

    if (preg_match('/<[\s]*script/ims', $html) || preg_match('/('.$events.')[\s]*=/ims', $html) || preg_match('/.*script\:/ims', $html)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$allow_iframe && preg_match('/<[\s]*(i?frame|form|input|embed|object)/ims', $html)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can see the test on `<script>` elements.

---

Now the solution would be to override `Product.php` classe and remove the validation on product descriptions.

Create the file (or update it) `/override/classes/Product.php`:

```php
<?php

class Product extends ProductCore
{
    public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
    {
        // Here we remove script validation on description_short field
        unset(static::$definition['fields']['description_short']['validate']);

        parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context);
    }
}
```

If you create this file, you will have to delete `/cache/class_index.php` so that Prestashop takes this override into account.

Tested and working.